# Android's alternatives to MIDP's drawing methods

Tags: java, android, java-me, midp

What are the Android's alternatives to MIDP's `Canvas.repaint()` and `Canvas.serviceRepaints()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View.invalidate()` if called from the UI thread and `View.postInvalidate()` if called from a non-UI thread, This will take care of `Canvas.repaint()`

I dont think android has an equivalent to `Canvas.serviceRepaints()`